# ViewDidLoad not getting invoked in child viewcontroller while using PSTCollectionViewController

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, viewdidload, childviewcontroller, pstcollectionview

I am using PSTCollectionView as an alternative to UICollectionView to have compatibility with iOS5 (as well as iOS6).  I am using storyboard to create my root viewcontroller then I add PSTCollecitonViewController programatically.  Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    DRCollectionVC *collectionVC = [[DRCollectionVC alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:[PSTCollectionViewFlowLayout new]];

    [collectionVC.collectionView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

    [self addChildViewController:collectionVC];
    [collectionVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:collectionVC.collectionView];

}
```

My DRCollectionVC is a subclass of PSTCollectionViewController.  The ViewDidLoad of DRCollectionVC is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.cellCount = 10;
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[DRCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MY_CELL"];


}
```

The above ViewDidLoad is not getting invoked.  I have tried similar approach with UICollectionView and that seems to work just fine.

Comment: Am also facing a problem to connect my viewcontroller to PSTCollectionview controller class

Comment: Can you do what you're needing to do in the child's implementation of `didMoveToParentViewController`?

Comment: I decided not supporting iOS5 so gave up on using PSTCollectionView